Driving a power relay using a MOSFET, Raspberry 4b, and a buck converter
I am trying to use my Raspberry Pi 4b GPIO pins to control a power relay through a MOSFET.
Power relay: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-devices/PR23-5V-900-1A/16752646
MOSFET: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/ZVN4424A/190148
Diode: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/1N4007-T/607
The relay coil of the power relay takes 5V. Hence, I'm using a MOSFET in the following circuit:

For some reason, regardless of whether I set the GPIO pin high or low, the MOSFET still conducts current. Things I've tried:

Replacing the 100 kOhm resistor with 50 kOhm resistor (and then trying a 10kOhm, 7.5kOhm, and 1 kOhm).
Removing the 100 Ohm resistor entirely.
Putting a 0.1 uF capacitor between the gate and the ground to remove noise.

I've prodded around with my oscilloscope, and the voltage applied to the gate of the MOSFET is nearly a perfect 0V (especially with the capacitor) when the GPIO is set to low and 3V when the GPIO is set to high. My power relay has 5 pins (according to the schematic/footprint I downloaded): A1, A2, COM1, COM2, and NO ("Normally Open"?). I assume A1 and A2 are the relay coil pins. I connected my 24V line to COM2 and my load to NO. From comparing the datasheet to the footprint (below), these two leads should be on opposite sides of the relay.

Does anyone know what my problem could be with my MOSFET? Is my MOSFET even the problem? Does anyone have any suggestions on changes to the circuit components if necessary? I'm fairly sure my wiring is correct, but I'm happy to send a picture of all the components jammed on a breadboard.
Thanks in advance! Please let me know if any clarifications are needed.

Please post pictures of your setup, I would guess you have the FET in reverse and the body diode is always conducting.

If 1k didn't work (which would fix an internal pull up issue), best guess is that the mosfet is not connected the right way or simply damaged


For some reason, regardless of whether I set the GPIO pin high or low, the MOSFET still conducts current.

A lot of time people misinterpret the pin out in the MOSFET data sheet: -

If you have Drain and Source reversed, the MOSFET behaves pretty much like a short with a small volt drop thus, it appears to activate the relay all the time.

Driving a power relay using a MOSFET, Raspberry 4b, and a buck
converter

I'm unsure why you mention a buck converter in your post.

I'm pretty sure I had it oriented correctly with source connected to ground and drain connected to my relay coil according to the datasheet. I swapped it around just to mess around and now it works. What?? Why would they swapped the drain and source leads on the packaging?? So lame. Anyways, thanks for all your help haha
